# Group Json array data with multiple fields using CROSS JOIN LATERAL on PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

This is `jsonb` field data:

```
[
   {'name': 'pratha', 'email': 'p@g.com', 'sub': { 'id': 1 } },
   {'name': 'pratha', 'email': 'c@d.com', 'sub': { 'id': 2 } }
]
```

When I want to get `name` and `email` fields, **I get duplicate fields**.

This is query:

```
SELECT jae.e->>'name', jae.e->>'email'
       FROM survey_results sr
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(sr.data_field) jae (e)
            GROUP BY jae.e->>'name', jae.e->>'email'
```

In this data, both objects' `name` is `pratha` but email is different. What I want to is grab one `pratha` and latest `email` in array.

Is it possible?

**Actual Result:**

```
pratha    p@g.com
pratha    c@d.com
```

**Expected Result:**

```
pratha    c@d.com
```

I only need name and email fields therefore, I want to group them by name.

See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9b55f/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not explained what *"latest email"*  means, but I presume you want the record with the highest `sub->id`

You may use `DISTINCT ON` to get a highest in a group.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (jae.e->>'name') --for every name
    jae.e->>'name'  as name, 
    jae.e->>'email' as email
       FROM survey_results sr
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(sr.data_field)  jae (e)
       ORDER BY jae.e->>'name', jae.e->'sub'->>'id' desc 
                                         --^ return only the row with the highest id
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7d0f079a7ece334366bc2796c245721b)